# How do i create code for a vlookup in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

df

| Season | Date | Team | Team_Season_Code | TS | L | Opponent | Opponent_Season_Code | OS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 20181109 | Abilene_Chr | 1_2019 | 94 | Home | Arkansas_St | 15_2019 | 73 |
| 2019 | 20181115 | Abilene_Chr | 1_2019 | 67 | Away | Denver | 82_2019 | 61 |
| 2019 | 20181122 | Abilene_Chr | 1_2019 | 72 | N | Elon | 70_2019 | 56 |
| 2019 | 20181123 | Abilene_Chr | 1_2019 | 73 | Away | Pacific | 224_2019 | 71 |
| 2019 | 20181124 | Abilene_Chr | 1_2019 | 60 | N | UC_Riverside | 306_2019 | 48 |

Overall_Season_Avg

| Team_Season_Code | Team | TS | OS | MOV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15_2019 | Arkansas_St | 70.909091 | 65.242424 | 5.666667 |
| 70_2019 | Elon | 73.636364 | 71.818182 | 1.818182 |
| 82_2019 | Denver | 74.03125 | 72.15625 | 1.875 |
| 224_2019 | Pacific | 78.333333 | 76.466667 | 1.866667 |
| 306_2019 | UC_Riverside | 79.545455 | 78.060606 | 1.484848 |

I have these two dataframes and I want to be able to look up the Opponent_Season_Code from df in Overall_Season_Avg - "Team_Season_Code" and bring back "TS" and "OS" to create a new column in df called "OOS" and "OTS"
So a new column for row 1 in df should have Column name OOS with data - 65.24... and Column name OTS with data 70.90...

In excel its a simple vlookup but i haven't been able to use the solutions that i have found to the vlookup question on overflow so i decided to post my own question. I will also say that the Overall_Season_Avg dataframe was created through by `Overall_Season_Avg = df.groupby(['Team_Season_Code', 'Team']).agg({'TS': np.mean, 'OS': np.mean, 'MOV': np.mean})`

Comment: With the provided data, the first row should be NaN, as there is no match for `15_2019` (the `Overall_Season_Avg` dataframe only has `15_2009`)

Comment: I fixed it...this is loose data just trying to be able to look up the code in the other dataframe.

Comment: Also, Denver/Elon have swapped codes. But check my answer and let me know if this works for you

Comment: It took me a bit to figure out how to put the dang table in the question box so i didn't check the info as well as i should have. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), after reworking a bit `Overall_Season_Avg` :

```
df.merge(Overall_Season_Avg
         .set_index(['Team_Season_Code', 'Team'])
         [['OS', 'TS']].add_prefix('O'),
         left_on=['Opponent_Season_Code', 'Opponent'],
         right_index=True, how='left'
        )
```

Output:

```
   Season      Date         Team Team_Season_Code  TS     L      Opponent Opponent_Season_Code  OS        OOS        OTS
0    2019  20181109  Abilene_Chr           1_2019  94  Home   Arkansas_St              15_2019  73  65.242424  70.909091
1    2019  20181115  Abilene_Chr           1_2019  67  Away        Denver              82_2019  61  72.156250  74.031250
2    2019  20181122  Abilene_Chr           1_2019  72     N          Elon              70_2019  56  71.818182  73.636364
3    2019  20181123  Abilene_Chr           1_2019  73  Away       Pacific             224_2019  71  76.466667  78.333333
4    2019  20181124  Abilene_Chr           1_2019  60     N  UC_Riverside             306_2019  48  78.060606  79.545455
```

###### merging only on `Opponent_Season_Code`/`Team_Season_Code`:

```
df.merge(Overall_Season_Avg
         .set_index('Team_Season_Code')
         [['OS', 'TS']].add_prefix('O'),
         left_on=['Opponent_Season_Code'],
         right_index=True, how='left'
        )
```

Output:

```
   Season      Date         Team Team_Season_Code  TS     L      Opponent Opponent_Season_Code  OS        OOS        OTS
0    2019  20181109  Abilene_Chr           1_2019  94  Home   Arkansas_St              15_2019  73  65.242424  70.909091
1    2019  20181115  Abilene_Chr           1_2019  67  Away        Denver              82_2019  61  72.156250  74.031250
2    2019  20181122  Abilene_Chr           1_2019  72     N          Elon              70_2019  56  71.818182  73.636364
3    2019  20181123  Abilene_Chr           1_2019  73  Away       Pacific             224_2019  71  76.466667  78.333333
4    2019  20181124  Abilene_Chr           1_2019  60     N  UC_Riverside             306_2019  48  78.060606  79.545455
```

Comment: Is there a way where they don't have to be in the correct row? Like it would go to Overall_Season_Avg and look for the Opponent_Season_Code in Team_Season_Code without it having to be in the exact row? Like 70_2019 is in the list of teams so i should get the data?

Comment: Essentially i could erase this entire problem in excel by a vlookup. Open up a column vlookup (lookup that cell (Opponent_Season_Code), in the table of Overall_Season_Avg, pull the 3rd column and done. I would rather not do it in excel.

Comment: @TSned3 the purpose of a merge is that is doesn't have to be in the exact row, if you shuffle the second DataFrame, the output will be the same. I can update the answer to merge only by "Opponent_Season_Code" though

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: I did and i got KeyError: "None of ['Team_Season_Code'] are in the columns"

Comment: Would it matter if my Overall_Season_Avg dataframe was created by a groupby? My first two columns are Team_Season_Code and Team but maybe they aren't actually columns. When i try to like copy the data in the dataframe it seems to think that the first two columns are different than the OS, TS, MOV columns.

Comment: @TSned3 hard to tell without an exact example, maybe worth opening a follow-up question?

Comment: Regarding your KeyError, this is not normal with the provided example, ensure that you use the correct column. Provide the output of `list(df)` for further info.

Comment: So when i print the first dataframe (or df) i get all the column headers.... ['Season', 'Date', 'Team', 'Team_Season_Code', 'TS', 'L', 'Opponent', 'Opponent_Season_Code', 'OS', 'MOV', 'Win', 'Lose'] but when i print the column the second dataframe (Season_Team_Code) I only get ['TS', 'OS', 'MOV']

Comment: maybe Team_Season_Code and Team are already in the index? In which case try to remove the `.set_index(['Team_Season_Code', 'Team'])` line

Comment: Overall_Season_Avg = df.groupby(['Team_Season_Code', 'Team']).agg({'TS': np.mean, 'OS': np.mean, 'MOV': np.mean}) thats the code for Overall_Season_Avg

Comment: They are in the index...it seems for what my limited knowledge of this can tell.

Answer (score -1):

```
df.merge(Overall_Season_Avg, on=['Team_Season_Code', 'Team'], how='left')
```

and rename column's names

or use `transform` instead `agg` when make Overall_Season_Avg.

but i don remain transform code becuz you don provide reproducible example

make simple and reproducible example plz

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example